# Set font to a character, but not the whole string in css or Javascript

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is it possible to set a font to a designated character? What I want is:

```
#test_id{
    font-family: "digitalfont";
    font-family-of-, : "HelveticaNeue-Light";
}
```

so that I can set a font to a comma and a different font to everything else. Or do I have to use `<span>` and surround the commas? Or can I achieve this with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to surround the comma, or use JavaScript to achieve this.

JS is something like this:

Html:

```
<div id="myText">Visit, Stackoverflow!</div>
```

jQuery + JS:

```
var myText = $("#myText").html();
myText = myText.replace(",", "<span>,</span>");
$("#myText").html(myText);
```

Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/am7j17hn/1/

Comment: So how would I do it with Javascript?